# Как можно наложить на камеру кадрирующую рамку

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Задача похожа на чтение QR кода.
Нужно проанализировать выделенный участок картинки с камеры. Хорошо бы в реальном времени.
Или хотя бы сфоткать и потом обработать.  Как можно выделить   что бы область в рамке была светлее фона?
Ну и возможно ли это в принципе средствами Delphi и FMX, или все же надо брать что то стороннее?
Если ткнете носом в пример буду весьма признателен.

[image: Примерно так]

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ тут https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/5421-how-to-design-qr-scan-focus-screen-with-fmx/
Результат удовлетворительный.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)